# Would Ants and Termites be considered r or K strategists?

Tags: evolutionary-game-theory, classification

My initial assumption is that most swarm species would fall under r strategists due to their prodigious number of offspring, but it also occurred to me that since worker types are non-propagating we would only consider the queen/drones which would be K. So which viewpoint is correct?

Comment: Its not an either or question, r and K are directions on a line scale.

Comment: @John I know, I just had some trouble phrasing the question. My question is more would the non-propagating workers affect the conclusion, or are only viable offspring factored into r/K?

Comment: What are r or K strategists? Your question is unclear to me.